# TensorFlow reusing Variable Scope

Tags: tensorflow

Here is my code in tensor flow, I have defined a Bi-LSTM and for a certain task I need to loop over my graph. although I have set reuse= True in Scope Variable, but it produces the error mentioned below the code.

```
for run in range(0, 2):


   with tf.variable_scope("LSTM", reuse= True) as scope:

     def LSTM(input_data):



        LSTM_cell_fw= tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units= hidden_size)
        LSTM_cell_bw= tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units= hidden_size)          
        output, states = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(LSTM_cell_fw, LSTM_cell_bw, inputs= input_data, dtype=tf.float32)
        output_1= output[0]
        output_2= output[1]
        output_1= output_1[-1, -1, :]
        output_1= tf.reshape(output_1, shape= (1, hidden_size))
        output_2= output_2[-1, -1, :]
        output_2= tf.reshape(output_2, shape= (1, hidden_size))
        fin_output= tf.concat((output_1, output_2), axis=1)

        return fin_output
```

and the error is: ValueError: Variable bidirectional_rnn/fw/basic_lstm_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

File "alpha-rep.py", line 65, in LSTM
    output, states = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(LSTM_cell_fw, LSTM_cell_bw, inputs= input_data, dtype=tf.float32)
  File "alpha-rep.py", line 77, in 
    out= LSTM(input_data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reuse a variable you **first** have to define it, only after that you can reuse it.

Define the function for defining the variables:

```
def LSTM(input_data):
    LSTM_cell_fw= tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units= hidden_size)
    LSTM_cell_bw= tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units= hidden_size)          
    output, states = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(LSTM_cell_fw, LSTM_cell_bw, inputs= input_data, dtype=tf.float32)
    output_1= output[0]
    output_2= output[1]
    output_1= output_1[-1, -1, :]
    output_1= tf.reshape(output_1, shape= (1, hidden_size))
    output_2= output_2[-1, -1, :]
    output_2= tf.reshape(output_2, shape= (1, hidden_size))
    return tf.concat((output_1, output_2), axis=1)
```

Then invoke it for the first time to define the variables and place it under the desired scope:

```
with tf.variable_scope("LSTM", reuse=False) as scope:
    first = LSTM(your_input_here)
```

Now you can define other layers under the same scope, reusing the already defined variables:

```
with tf.variable_scope("LSTM", reuse=True) as scope:
    second = LSTM(your_other_input_here)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, you mean for example here for the first time that the graph is working (run=0) the reuse shall be false and when run>0 it shall be True, right?